# Excel data validation rule involving two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

The rule is "You can enter a number in this column or in the column next to it, but both columns cannot have a value (on the same row) unless one of them is zero.

These are all valid:

```
A.....B.
0.....2.5
3.....0
0.....0
```

This would not be valid:

```
A.....B
1.5...2
```

I don't work much with Excel. Is that sort of rule possible?

P.S. If possible I'd like to "invalidate" the entry by turning it to zero.

Additional edit:  Either of these actions would be OK if the rule is not met: a) whichever cell of the pair of cell was last updated should be set to zero; or b) the other cell should be set to zero if there's no way to avoid a circular reference error.

Simply put, I am trying to PREVENT there being more than one non-zero value in the pair of cells, not merely give some visual indication that there is more than one non-zero value in the pair.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but how do you want the rule to manifest itself? You can use conditional formatting to change cell colors. Or, you can use a formula in a third column that could state "valid" or "invalid". You could even do a filter on the two columns that could hide/show the valid. You could create a VBA program that could execute the rule. There are other possibilities.You need to add more context and let us know what you have tried. Then we can provide more help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can I cause the "bad" entry to become zero?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wish to have one of the following occur:

a) whichever cell of the pair of cells was last updated should be set to zero, or

b) the other cell should be set to zero.

OK, I am not sure that the first option can be met, but the 2nd one definitely can.

In cell `A1` type the following formula:

`=IF(B1<>"",IF(B1<>0,0,""),"")`

In cell `B1` type the following formula:

`=IF(A1<>"",IF(A1<>0,0,""),"")`

You will start with a circular reference (both formulae will indirectly refer to itself), but as soon as you type a number in either column, the circular reference will disappear and the formula left in that row will take over giving you a zero if the other cell is not zero, and if the other cell is zero, it will leave the cell blank for another zero or a different number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not a third column. Whichever one of those two cells was last updated should become zero if there's more than one non-zero value in the pair of cells. When I try to adapt your formula to that purpose, I get a circular reference error. `=IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0),A1,0)` and for the second cell of the pair  `=IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0),B1,0)`  As an alternative, I could change the other cell of the pair to 0, if that would avoid the circular reference. But I'm not sure how to set the value of another cell from within a formula.